# how remove dots in canvas html?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Firstly, I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve it but no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

**Problem:** Remove Only **Red** Dot without a clear canvas.

**I want to Remove only Red Dotes not Full Canvas Remove or Reload .**

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(36, 100, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.fillStyle = "Orange";
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(123, 100, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.fillStyle = "Green";
context.fill();

function removeRedDot(){
 // remove code
 alert('Remove Red Dot');
}
```

```css
#canvas{
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Approach the circle with the mouse</h4> <button onclick="removeRedDot()"> Red Remove Dot</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: Well.. is that even possible? You could probably "paint" over it. But otherwise, clear it and re-render it without the red dot?

Comment: Do you know which are the red dots? If yes, you could save the parameters of the coreesponding `context.arc` into a variable and just fill them white

Comment: Why don't you want to clear all? That's just how it should be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you drew the red circle at (`x`, `y`) position (`100px`, `100px`) with a diameter of `6px`, the area it takes up is:

```
x      : 100 - (6 / 2)
y      : 100 - (6 / 2)
width  : 6
height : 6
```

You can clear a section of the canvas with the `clearRect` method.

```js
context.clearRect(97, 97, 6, 6);
```

If your canvas has a background, you will either need to clear the entire canvas and redraw everything except for the red dot, or you could call `fillRect`… assuming that `context.fillStyle` is set to the background color.

```js
context.fillRect(97, 97, 6, 6);
```

You would somehow have to know where the red dot was painted (and what size it was), prior to painting it.

**Edit:** See my OOP example following the demo below!

---

### Demo

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(36, 100, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.fillStyle = "Orange";
context.fill();

context.beginPath();
context.arc(123, 100, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true); // Outer circle
context.lineWidth = 0;
context.fillStyle = "Green";
context.fill();

function removeRedDot() {
  context.clearRect(97, 97, 6, 6);
  alert('Removed Red Dot');
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Approach the circle with the mouse</h4> <button onclick="removeRedDot()"> Red Remove Dot</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
```

---

### OOP to the rescue!

A better approach would be knowing about the red dot outside the canvas rendering. You could wrap the canvas context inside a class that manages layers and drawables.

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

const main = () => {
  const canvas = new Canvas(ctx);
  const layer = canvas.addLayer();
  const circles = [
    new Circle({ x: 50, y: 50 }, 3, 'red'),
    new Circle({ x: 100, y: 100 }, 6, 'green'),
    new Circle({ x: 150, y: 150 }, 12, 'blue')
  ];
  layer.add(...circles);
  canvas.render();
  
  // After 2 second, remove the red dot and re-render.
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('Removing "red" circle, and adding a "cyan" circle...');
    layer.remove(circles[0]);
    layer.add(new Circle({ x: 150, y: 50 }, 8, 'cyan'));
    canvas.render();
  }, 2000);
};

class Drawable {
  constructor(origin) {
    this.origin = origin;
  }
  draw(ctx) { }
}

class Layer {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.drawables = [];
  }
  add(...drawables) {
    drawables.forEach(drawable => this.drawables.push(drawable));
  }
  remove(drawableOrIndex) {
    if (isNaN(drawableOrIndex)) {
      drawableOrIndex = this.drawables.indexOf(drawableOrIndex);
    }
    if (drawableOrIndex > -1) {
      this.drawables.splice(drawableOrIndex, 1);
    }
  }
  render(ctx) {
    this.drawables.forEach(drawable => drawable.render(ctx));
  }
}

class Canvas {
  constructor(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.layers = [];
  }
  addLayer(name) {
    const newLayer = new Layer(name || 'layer-' + this.layers.length);
    this.layers.push(newLayer);
    return newLayer;
  }
  getLayer(nameOrIndex) {
    return isNaN(nameOrIndex)
      ? this.layers.find(layer => layer.name === nameOrIndex)
      : this.layers[nameOrIndex];
  }
  render() {
    const { width, height } = this.ctx.canvas;
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    this.layers.forEach(layer => layer.render(this.ctx));
  }
}

class Circle extends Drawable {
  constructor(origin, radius, color) {
    super(origin);
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
  }
  render(ctx) {
    const { x, y } = this.origin;
    const diameter = this.radius * 2;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.lineWidth = 0;
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}

main();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: can you please explain context.clearRect(97, 97, 6, 6) ?

Comment: Just wanted to point out, that his does not *remove the red dot*. It paints over it with a transparent brush. Anything in that *rect* will be erased. It is kinda similar to just paint a white dot at the same position as the red dot in this case.

Comment: @JavaScript I added an OOP example below, but why would you paint a white dot? The canvas should be transparent by nature, or you would have to know what the background color is anyways.

Comment: @Sumitpatel Added more explanation and an OOP example at the bottom.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl can you help against. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/35srfjnm/ .. after removing red dote i want to set black color (previous color )..not canvas background color

Comment: @Sumitpatel You would have to know what the color underneath the black dot is and then fill a rectangle instead of clearing it. e.g. `context.fillStyle = "black"; context.fillRect(97, 97, 6, 6);` Since this is too difficult to maintain as you have it, I suggest you adopt the OOP example at the bottom of the response above.

Comment: but one problem i have set dynamically so I am not sure which the previous color set .. so how can achieve that?  Example one other image is there and replace on dot but remove dots then set prev image or drawing

Comment: @Sumitpatel As I said, take a look at the example at the _VERY_ bottom of my answer. Replace the timeout logic with a button handler. If you do not understand this, you will need to rethink your script and study OOP principles.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl please read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63857648/canvas-restore-image-after-removing-object-on-it  I have the same problem can solve it

Answer (score 0):

As the existing answer has demonstrated the OO adage...

- *"I asked for a banana, but got a gorilla in the jungle holding a banana."*,

I have added this answer to demonstrate a more concise JavaScript unique OO approach.

The reason: The battle against complexity.

Complexity is a coders number one enemy, adding unneeded layers of abstraction, duplicating existing behaviours, anticipating undefined needs, all add complexity.

Thought it may not matter if there is only less than 100 lines, for large projects the additional code adds up quickly, and every line is an additional source of bugs.

JavaScript provides a simple and very flexible OO model, with an emphasis on polymorphism via ad hoc object construction and extension. It also has a substantial set of coding shortcuts that go a long way in reducing the number of lines need to implement behaviours

The result is half as much code with almost the same functionality,

### Example

- Uses the `Array` prototype to implement layers
- `circle` Inherits `drawable` by passing a type to constructor.
- Removes by `color`, rather than index or reference

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const P2 = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x,y});
const Drawable = (pos, color, size = 10, type = Circle) => ({pos, size, color, ...type});
const Circle = {
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
};
const drawables = Object.assign([], {
       draw(ctx) { for (const d of this) { d.draw(ctx) } },
       remove(color) {
           const idx = this.findIndex(d => d.color === color);
           return (idx > -1 && (this.splice(idx, 1)[0])) || undefined;
       },
    }
);
drawables.push(...[...document.querySelectorAll("#buttons button")].map((but, idx)=>
    Drawable(P2(100 + idx * 100, 50), but.dataset.color)
));
drawables.draw(ctx);   
buttons.addEventListener("click", e => {
    if (drawables.remove(e.target.dataset.color)) {
       ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
       drawables.draw(ctx);
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
<div id="buttons">
    <button data-color="red">Remove Red</button>
    <button data-color="green">Remove Green</button>
    <button data-color="blue">Remove Blue</button>
</div>
```

(And I will add that there is nothing wrong with [Mr. Polywhirl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63846316/3877726) code)

Comment: please read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63857648/canvas-restore-image-after-removing-object-on-it  I have the same problem can solve it